# Check if a vector of strings is a substring in one of elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a vector of strings like

```
a1 = ["arp", "live", "strong"]

a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]
```

How would I check if armstrong is a substring of strong in a1. using C++

I would do two for loops and check if a string is a substring in a2, but I want an efficient approach.

```
std::vector<std::string> inArray(std::vector<std::string> &array1, std::vector<std::string> &array2)
{
    vector<string> result;
    for (string &s : array1)
    {
        for (string &d : array2)
        {

            if (s.find(d) != string::npos)
            {
                cout << d << endl;
            }
        }

    }

    return result;

}

int main() {

    vector<string> a = { "arp", "live", "strong" };
    vector<string> b = { "lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong" };

    vector<string> result = inArray(a, b);

}
```

Given two arrays of strings a1 and a2 return a sorted array r in lexicographical order of the strings of a1 which are substrings of strings of a2.

```
Example 1:

a1 = ["arp", "live", "strong"]

a2 = ["lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong"]

returns ["arp", "live", "strong"]
```

Comment: Why do you think its unefficient, have you measured it ? If so, post the code

Comment: it is O(N*M). Would it be better than that ?

Comment: "How would I check if armstrong is a substring of strong in a1" Don't you want to check the other way around?

Comment: And please describe how you expect the result to be and show us what you have done so far to get there.

Comment: @SimonKraemer It's the other way around, I will post the code now.

Comment: That code won't even compile due to the double usage of `d`. Also you don't add anything to the vector.

Comment: @SimonKraemer The vector will contain the results. I have not reached the step so far. so I just want to check if string in a is a substring in b

Comment: The only efficiency improvement I can think of would be a non-generic approach that takes the kind of data into account. e.g. If the data is more likely to have the substring at the end of the string you could use `rfind` instead of `find` or maybe you can speed up things a little by sorting the data in a special way - but that really is specialized stuff that might become even slower than your current approach when the data changes.

Comment: How about you implement your solution and then ask for improvements on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Why do you have to find a more efficient solution? Are you processing millions of strings? If yes, is the number of strings in `a1` small and in `a2` large, or the other way around, or about equal?

Comment: @SimonKraemer It seems that the above code does not work either. I test it and it doesn't work.

Comment: First of all I already told you: "Also you don't add anything to the vector.", Second of all you did not yet show us what you intend to do or what your result should be. Shall we guess? That's not how this side works.

Comment: @SimonKraemer I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: Use names for the variables and functions that make it easy to identify the purpose

Second: A vector will not magically fill itself.

Third: You are currently searching for the full strings within the substrings (see first)

Fourth: Pass the value by const reference if you don't plan on modifying it.

Fifth: According to your expected answer you don't want duplicates. I would suggest using `std::set` for this purpose as it doesn't allow duplicates.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::set;
using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;

set<string> getMatchingSubstrings(const vector<string> &subStrings, const vector<string> &fullStrings)
{   
    set<string> result;
    for (const string &fullString : fullStrings)
    {
        for (const string &subString : subStrings)
        {
            if (fullString.find(subString) != string::npos)
            {
                result.insert(subString);
            }
        }

    }
    return result;
}

int main() {

    vector<string> a = { "arp", "live", "strong" };
    vector<string> b = { "lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong" };
    set<string> result = getMatchingSubstrings(a, b);
}
```

A slightly faster approach might be remove the already found substrings from the initial list so you don't have to check for these twice. In this case the result won't be sorted, so if you need to sort again this might not be the best choice.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::vector;
using std::string;
using std::cout;

std::vector<std::string> getMatchingSubstrings(const std::vector<std::string> &subStrings, const std::vector<std::string> &fullStrings)
{   
    vector<string> unmatchedSubStrings = subStrings;
    vector<string> matchedSubStrings;
    for (const string &fullString : fullStrings)
    {
        if (unmatchedSubStrings.empty()) break;
        for (auto subStringIter = unmatchedSubStrings.begin(); subStringIter != unmatchedSubStrings.end();)
        {
            const string& subString = *subStringIter;
            if (fullString.find(subString) != string::npos)
            {
                matchedSubStrings.push_back(subString);
                subStringIter = unmatchedSubStrings.erase(subStringIter);
            }
            else
            {
                ++subStringIter;
            }
        }
    }

    return matchedSubStrings;
}

int main() {

    vector<string> a = { "arp", "live", "strong" };
    vector<string> b = { "lively", "alive", "harp", "sharp", "armstrong" };

    vector<string> result = getMatchingSubstrings(a, b);

}
```